# A number-theoretic random walk on the integers

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, random-walk

Suppose a random walker starts at $S_0 = 2$, and walks according to the following transition probabilities:

- If the walker is on the $n$th prime number $p_n$, she moves to either
  $p_n + 1$ or $p_{n+1}$ with equal probability.
- If the walker is on a
  composite number $x$, she moves to one of the prime factors of $x$,
  each with probability $1/\omega(x)$, where $\omega(n)$ denotes the
  number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

**I am interested in determining the quantity $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{n\ge 0} S_n = \infty)$. In particular, is this probability 1 or less than 1?** Heuristically, there are so many "traps" for the walker to lose progress that it seems possible for the probability to be less than 1. On the other hand, infinity is quite a while, and there is always a positive chance, however small, of going further than the furthest point reached at up to that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This random walk is highly biased to the left. By the prime number theorem, $p_n$ grows asymptotically like $n \ln n$, so starting from a prime number $p_n$, there is a $1/2$ probability of moving to $p_{n+1}$ in one step, which on average for large primes is an increase of a factor of $\frac{(n+1) \ln(n+1)}{n \ln n} \approx 1+1/n$, whereas with probability $1/2$ in two steps it moves to a number $\le \frac{p_n+1}2$, a decrease of factor of $\le 1/2$. This shows that this walk will be recurrent, but since it never gets absorbed, the probability of reaching or exceeding the $N$-th prime number, starting anywhere, is always $\ge 2^{-N}>0$, so by the law of large numbers this will happen almost surely, infinitely often, and so $\sup S_n = \infty$ almost surely.